# Having issue while recursively parsing xml using Stax and xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, stax

While reading the xml file recursively using Stax and xslt, I am only getting 1st iteration data. It is not moving to the next ones.

Here is my sample xml data:

```
<Root node>
 <ParentNode>
   <ChildNode1 a1, a2, a3,a4 ...>
      <SubChild1 b1, b2, b3, b4 ../>
      <SubChild2 c1, c2, c3, c4 ../>
      <SubChild3 d1, d2, d3, d4 ..>
            <GrandChild1  e1, e2, e3, e4 ../>
            <GrandChild2  f1, f2, f3, f4 ../>
            <GrandChild3  g1, g2, g3, g4 ../>
      </SubChild3>
   <ChildNode1>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   .
   .
   .
   <ChildNode2>
   . . . .
   </ChildNode2>
   ------ This is 1 iteration from ChildNode1 to Chn ------
   <ChildNode1 a1, a2, a3,a4 ...>
      <SubChild1 b1, b2, b3, b4 ../>
      <SubChild2 c1, c2, c3, c4 ../>
      <SubChild3 d1, d2, d3, d4 ..>
            <GrandChild1  e1, e2, e3, e4 ../>
            <GrandChild2  f1, f2, f3, f4 ../>
            <GrandChild3  g1, g2, g3, g4 ../>
      </SubChild3>
   <ChildNode1>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   .
   .
   .
    <ChildNode2>
   . . . .
   </ChildNode2>
   ------ This is 2 iteration from ChildNode1 to Chn ------
   <ChildNode1 a1, a2, a3,a4 ...>
      <SubChild1 b1, b2, b3, b4 ../>
      <SubChild2 c1, c2, c3, c4 ../>
      <SubChild3 d1, d2, d3, d4 ..>
            <GrandChild1  e1, e2, e3, e4 ../>
            <GrandChild2  f1, f2, f3, f4 ../>
            <GrandChild3  g1, g2, g3, g4 ../>
      </SubChild3>
   <ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   <ChildNode2 h1, h2, h3 ...>
      <SubChild4 i1, i2, i3 ...>
          <GrandChild4 j1, j2, j3 .../>
          <GrandChild5 k1, k2, k3 .../>
      </SubChild4>
      <SubChild5>
         <GrandChild6>
            <GreatGrandChild1 l1, l2, l3 ../>
         </GrandChild6>
      </SubChild5>
   </ChildNode2>
   .
   .
   .
    <ChildNode2>
   . . . .
   </ChildNode2>
   ------like this we have n number of Iterations------
 </ParentNode>
</Root node>
```

This is my sample xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                          xmlns:x="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2" 
                          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2 fixml-main-5-0-SP2_.xsd"
                          xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
                          exclude-result-prefixes="xs math">

  <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="'|'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />



  <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:text> a1 | a2| d1| d2| e1| e2| f1| f2| h1| h2| h3| j1| j2| k1| k2| l1 </xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::x:ParentNode"/>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="x:ParentNode">

 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/@a1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/@a2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/x.SubChild3/@d1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/x.SubChild3/@d2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/x.SubChild3/x.GrandChild1/@e1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/x.SubChild3/x.GrandChild1/@e2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/x.SubChild3/x.GrandChild2/@f1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode1/x.SubChild3/x.GrandChild2/@f2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />


 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/@h1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/@h2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/@h3))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/x:GrandChild4/@j1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/x:GrandChild4/@j2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/x:GrandChild5/@k1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild4/x:GrandChild5/@k2))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( normalize-space(x:ChildNode2/x:SubChild5/x.GrandChild6/x.GreatGrandChild1/@l1))" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my Java code:

```
public class Xml2Csv {

public static int transform(InputStream is, OutputStream os, Transformer transformer, QName name) throws XMLStreamException, TransformerException {
    long time1 = System.nanoTime();
    // Open input & output files
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, false);
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);
    // In case you want to check which implementation is used.
    // Woodstox is a bit faster, but not worth adding extra dependency.
   //        System.out.println("Reader="+reader);
//        System.out.println("Transformer="+transformer);

    Result result = new StreamResult(os);

    int count = 0;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT && name.equals(reader.getName())) {
            // System.out.println("FOUND " + count);
            count++;
            transformer.transform(new StAXSource(reader), result);
            if (count % 1000 == 0) {
                long time2 = System.nanoTime();
                double ms = (time2 - time1) / 1000000.0;
                System.out.format("Time=%.2fms Rows=%d%n", ms, count);
            }
        } else if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
//                    System.out.println("Start "+reader.getName()+" != "+name);
        }
        reader.next();
    }
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();
    double ms = (time2 - time1) / 1000000.0;
    System.out.format("Total Time=%.2fms Total rows=%d%n", ms, count);
    return count;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
    // Parse command line options
    File xsltFile;
    File inputFile;
    File outputFile;
    String tagName;
    String namespace;
    try {
        String xsltFileName = parse("-x", arg, "XSLT sheet", true);
        String inputFileName = parse("-f", arg, "Input file", true);
        String outputFileName = parse("-o", arg, "Output file", true);
        tagName = parse("-t", arg, "Tag name", true);
        namespace = parse("-n", arg, "Tag Namespace URL", false);
        xsltFile = new File(xsltFileName);
        inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Syntax: Xml2Csv -f <input file> -o <output file> -x <XSLT stylesheet> -t <Tag name> [-n <namespace URL>]");
        System.err.println("Will split given file on given tag with given namespace.");
        System.err.println("Will process contents of each tag using given XSLT.");
        System.exit(1);
        return;
    }
    if (!xsltFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found " + xsltFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (!inputFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Open XSLT stylesheet
    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

    // Create XML tag name which is used to break up XML into rows
    final QName name;
    if (namespace != null) {
        name = new QName(namespace, tagName);
    } else {
        name = new QName(tagName);
    }
    System.out.println("Will look for tag " + name + " in namespace " + namespace);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        // Open input & output files
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        transform(fis, fos, transformer, name);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}

// Teo - inefficient, but who cares
private static String parse(String option, String[] arg, String desc, boolean required) throws ParseException {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        if (option.equals(arg[i])) {
            if (i + 1 < arg.length) {
                String value = arg[i + 1].trim();
                return value;
            } else {
                throw new ParseException(option + " must be followed by an argument", i);
            }
        }
    }
    if (required) {
        throw new ParseException(desc + " is required", 0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
a1 | a2| d1| d2| e1| e2| f1| f2| h1| h2| h3| j1| j2| k1| k2| l1
```

I should get all the iterations data but instead I am getting only one Iteration data.

Could you guys help me where can I change the code to get all the Iterations data ?

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. I am afraid that "XML" you have posted is not well-formed XML at all and it certainly does not have any namespace declarations at all so it is obvious that the XSLT with matches like `x:ParentNode` will never match.

Comment: Why does your title talk about processing the input recursively when your stylesheet contains no recursion at all? Surely you can simplify this to the essence of the problem while still showing us some XML in proper XML notation?